# running hadoop on Google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, hadoop, mapreduce

Is it possible to run map reduce jobs on Google app engine?

Any reference or tutorial would help

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort of.

You can't use the actual MapReduce framework - the architecture is too incompatible with AppEngine.

However, there is an equivalent system built specficially for GAE - [appengine-mapreduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/). That site is a bit confusing, as the first version of the code only supported mappers, without the subsequent reduce step - recently they released a version with full mapreduce support, but some of the documentation still referes to the earlier mapper-only one.

The best introduction is the GoogleIO [talk from Mike Aizatskyi](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIxelKcyCC0).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run Hadoop on Appengine (No filesystem access as well).

You may want to check AWS ElasticMapreduce. Its a cloud based platform for running Mapreduce jobs.

[ElasticMapreduce](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full documentation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/overview

Answer (score 0):

Saw this Google Cloud Platform advertisement: 
Hadoop on Google Compute Engine virtual machines 
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/hadoop